# Fixing 40/60 Catalan/English translation in Flameshot when locale is set to Norwegian!

Tags: locale

I use Flameshot for capturing screenshot and I noticed the configuration was in some unknown language. After deciding it was not Italian (too many x's), I am pretty sure it is Catalan (regional language in Spain). I do not speak Catalan and I have not set it as any preference on my system. Herein lies the mystery!

[image]
[image]

As can be seen, the locale is set to nb_NO ("norwegian bokmål Norway"). The language setting is the same. Catalan is not in the list of locales either, so I guess the language strings come from some bundled Flameshot language files. Any idea how I can force it to use English-only, given that Norwegian does not seem to be an option? Here I am am *assuming* that the product has been fully translated to English, of course, but it could of course be that the main developer is Catalan and could not be bothered to do make translation strings for the entire app :)

Comment: The locale categories you show us are irrelevant to translation. Please edit your question and show the output of the `locale` command.

Comment: But probably there is a language chooser somewhere in the settings of the application.